# Is it true that coercions have no run-time cost?

Tags: ocaml

I always assumed that coercions in OCaml (the `:>` operator) are only needed to satisfy the type-checker but do not cause any code to be generated. Is that actually true?

Comment: The title could more clearly match the question - I'm not sure that `O(0)` makes sense.

Comment: What kind of coercions are you talking about?

Comment: @MarkPattison that would just go to `O(1)` aka constant time.

Comment: @Étienne Millon: I am only aware of one kind of coercions in OCaml, the `:>` ones.
@Mark Pattison & Daniel A. White: O(0) is valid and different from O(1). Although just 0 would have been more precise.
Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about [supertype coercion](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#s%3acoercions), like `(expr : type :> supertype)`.

Yes, this operation takes place at compile time, in the type checker. There's nothing happening at runtime, where it takes 0 time. This is because (in OCaml), coercions are allowed only when they are type safe. So there's nothing to check at runtime.